# Qt - can QTable have column labels rotated by 90 degrees?

Tags: qt, qtablewidget

I have many narrow columns with very long labels. I want to rotate the labels by 90 degrees. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will probably have to subclass [QTableWidgetItem](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qtablewidgetitem.html) and implement your own vertical text painting. Then use `setHorizontalHeaderItem()` on your table to point to an instance of your new widget.

Answer (score 2):

When searching for an answer to this questions I found many hints, but no real answer. The hints tell one to subclass QHeaderView and re-implement paintSection. When I tried to do so in PyQt4 and tried to implement paintSection from scratch, following the source of QHeaderView, I was not successful. However, simply rotating the painter instance and adjusting all the size hints was successful. 
The code works for horizontal headers only and is nicely compact:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class RotatedHeaderView( QtGui.QHeaderView ):
    def __init__(self, orientation, parent=None ):
        super(RotatedHeaderView, self).__init__(orientation, parent)
        self.setMinimumSectionSize(20)

    def paintSection(self, painter, rect, logicalIndex ):
        painter.save()
        # translate the painter such that rotate will rotate around the correct point
        painter.translate(rect.x()+rect.width(), rect.y())
        painter.rotate(90)
        # and have parent code paint at this location
        newrect = QtCore.QRect(0,0,rect.height(),rect.width())
        super(RotatedHeaderView, self).paintSection(painter, newrect, logicalIndex)
        painter.restore()

    def minimumSizeHint(self):
        size = super(RotatedHeaderView, self).minimumSizeHint()
        size.transpose()
        return size

    def sectionSizeFromContents(self, logicalIndex):
        size = super(RotatedHeaderView, self).sectionSizeFromContents(logicalIndex)
        size.transpose()
        return size
```

Answer (score 2):

I've made a custom script that works fine based on previous answer..

copy and paste the next code in a rotated.py file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class RotatedHeaderView(QHeaderView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(RotatedHeaderView, self).__init__(Qt.Horizontal, parent)
        self.setMinimumSectionSize(20)

    def paintSection(self, painter, rect, logicalIndex ):
        painter.save()
        # translate the painter such that rotate will rotate around the correct point
        painter.translate(rect.x()+rect.width(), rect.y())
        painter.rotate(90)
        # and have parent code paint at this location
        newrect = QRect(0,0,rect.height(),rect.width())
        super(RotatedHeaderView, self).paintSection(painter, newrect, logicalIndex)
        painter.restore()

    def minimumSizeHint(self):
        size = super(RotatedHeaderView, self).minimumSizeHint()
        size.transpose()
        return size

    def sectionSizeFromContents(self, logicalIndex):
        size = super(RotatedHeaderView, self).sectionSizeFromContents(logicalIndex)
        size.transpose()
        return size
```

then import from your main.py file this class using this line:

```
from rotated import RotatedHeaderView
```

and complete the actions with this line:

```
self.YourTableName.setHorizontalHeader(RotatedHeaderView(self.YourTableName))
```

hope worth it!